# JDBC via Python can't work with jpype & jaydebeapi, when I changed JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, python, oracle

Could someone help me?

```
JHOME = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
if not jpype.isJVMStarted():
    jpype.startJVM(JHOME, '-Djava.class.path=ojdbc8.jar')


con = jaydebeapi.connect('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver','jdbc:oracle:thin:XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX@//99.99.99.99:1521/XXX')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT NAME FROM M_ITEM WHERE ITEMID='" + t.get() + "'")

row = cur.fetchone()  
messagebox.showinfo("Result", row[0])
cur.close()
con.close()
```

This code is to connect to a Oracle Database server.
When I had set JAVA_HOME environment variable up "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1", The program have worked without any error.

But after I changed JAVA_HOME environment variable setting, the following error has occured.

"jpype._jvmfinder.JVMNotFoundException: No JVM shared library file (jvm.dll) found. Try setting up the JAVA_HOME environment variable properly"

I have tried these for JAVA_HOME environment variable, but everything below semed not to be proper.

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_75

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_221

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7

What is wrong? When I chose jre1.8.0_221 for JAVA_HOME, I guess it should be fine though.
This problem is happening on the same computer which I could connect to. I plan on distributing this app to another computer, So I 'm testing with another setting with JAVA.
Although my version of Jpype is different this one on [the web page](https://pypi.org/project/JPype1/0.7.1/), the latest version should look fine with my JAVA8 on JAVA_HOME and Python3.6.
My Jpype is 0.6.3.
Does anyone know whether my version of Jpype support JAVA8 and Python3.6?

Or should I suspect another problem?